# Modifying mydestination directive in postfix MTA

Tags: 16.04, email, postfix

I'm not good in English and I cannot understand what does this mean:

[image]

I've followed the first code block of image above and my current configuration looks like this:

```
. . . 
mydestination = $myhostname, lamtakam.com, Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal, localhost.localdomain, , localhost
. . .
```

What change should I make now?

---

**Note:** `lamtakam.com` is the same as `example.com` in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct the line to:

```
mydestination = $myhostname, lamtakam.com, localhost.localdomain, localhost
```

Save and restart postfix service.

Comment: I see, ok thank you, upvote. Just what's `localhost.$mydomain $mydomain` which is into the second block of the image in my question? *(which is highlighted)*

Comment: When the mydomain is included and populated in your main.cf file then you can also include localhost.$mydomain $mydomain like this: mydomain = lamtakam.com

Comment: look, do you know why the email I send goes to spam (not inbox)?

Comment: Perhaps the lamtakam.com domain is on the blacklist. Some automatic e-mail filters when you include a http link in the message automatically go to spam.

Comment: I hardly think the reason be related to domain is on the blacklist. Because few month ago, I sent emails (which went to inbox as well) on another server.

Comment: Check this: https://www.serverintellect.com/support/email/avoid-spam/

Comment: It might be related to your hostname. Set up myhostname=mail.lamtakam.com or myhostname=lamtakam.com

Comment: And restart postfix service.

Comment: I changed the hostname but wasn't useful :-(

Comment: You will need most probably a valid helo/ehlo domain. Check here: https://www.linuxmagic.com/best_practices/valid_helo_domain.html

Comment: Also check your /var/log/mail.log for errors.

Comment: Ok, there are some lines in `mail.log` which doesn't seem related to the current problem. Ca you please connect to my server and take a look at it if I give you user and password?

Comment: Edit your question and paste your mail.log lines there. Only the relevant ones.

Comment: I've asked a new question here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007352/why-the-email-i-send-goes-into-spam