# Why the email I send goes into spam?

Tags: 16.04, server, email, postfix, mail

I use ubuntu 16.04 on my server and recently I've installed postfix MTA on my server following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-16-04).

The problem is the email I send goes into spam, not inbox. Any idea what's wrong and how can I fix it? Noted that my domain name isn't into black list. Because few months ago, I did in on another server and emails sent as well *(they went into inbox)*.

Also I send email via command line interface like this:

```
echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "This is the subject line" <my_email>
```

What should I do now?

---

Also [this](https://gist.github.com/sajadshafizadeh/30f1d4af2585882fd0db2b402842c9cc) is my `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file on the server and this is my DNS records on cloudflare:

[image]

Comment: You can check config if send mail to `check-auth@verifier.port25.com` from your mail server. You will see is messages signed or not, also `SPF` and `DKIM` and other records are good or not

Comment: Are the MX settings correct? To me it seems that MX record should be MX lamtakam.com     lamtakam.com

Comment: @2707974 I've executed this command: `echo "test" | mail -s "test" check-auth@verifier.port25.com`. What's next?

Comment: You most probably use wrong MX value for your domain. Correct value should be lamtakam.com, supposing you are hosting your mail server by yourself.

Comment: You will receive mail from `check-auth@verifier.port25.com` on email address from `FROM' field with result.

Comment: @kukulo emm, you know, I want to use zoho for receiving emails and use my own smtp server for sending email. Is it right?

Answer (score 1):

In the last year, several mail providers (most notably GMail) have started to put all Emails received without TLS into the spam folder. Try adding the following lines to your postfix configuration:

```
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
```

After doing `systemctl reload postfix` follow the instructions at
https://www.port25.com/authentication-checker/
to validate your setup.

Comment: Still it goes into spam